# Parcel and react 18 project set up error. @parcel/transformer-js: Unexpected token `)`. Expected this, import, async, function

Tags: parceljs, react-18

Server running at http://localhost:1234
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: Unexpected token `)`. Expected this, import, async, function, [ for array literal, { for object literal, @ for
decorator, function, class, null, true, false, number, bigint, string, regexp, ` for template literal, (, or an identifier

/home/sizzions/Desktop/Projects/web app/WenApp/src/index.js:5:19

> 4 | const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript

> > 5 | root.render(/);
> > |                   ^
> > [image: Parcel error]

```
`import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
 import App from './App';
   const container = document.getElementById('app');

   const root = createRoot(container); // createRoot(container!) if you use TypeScript
 root.render(<App/>);`
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I ran into this for a few minutes until I realized react wasn't no longer in my package.json file. After adding react 18 back in I was good to move on to my next error. :)

Comment: Me i had to recheck all config file from tsconfig to tailwindconfig